# Selenium copying the wrong info when using get_attribute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from a table and I'm using the find by ID method. I'm working in Jupyter Notebook, but I realized I needed to put all of the scrape code together to be able to iterate through every submission of a web form that I needed to do.

So I put all my code that was previously working to scrape data from this table:

```
for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
    input_value = row["Street Address"]

# Find the street address input element and submit the form
address_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'esri-search__input')
address_input.clear()
address_input.send_keys(input_value)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'esri-icon-search').click()

# Wait for the page to load and parse the HTML
driver.implicitly_wait(20)  # Adjust the wait time if needed
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Wait for the table to be visible
table_locator = (By.ID, 'MatchAddr')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(table_locator))

# Find the table elements by IDs
match_addr = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'MatchAddr')
msa_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'MSACode')
state_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'StateCode')
county_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'CountyCode')
tract_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'TractCode')
msa_name = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'MSAName')
state_name = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'StateName')
county_name = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'CountyName')

# Iterate over the elements and extract the text content
for i in range(len(match_addr)):
    row = [
        match_addr[i].get_attribute('MatchAddr'),
        msa_code[i].get_attribute('MSACode'),
        state_code[i].get_attribute('StateCode'),
        county_code[i].get_attribute('CountyCode'),
        tract_code[i].get_attribute('TractCode'),
        msa_name[i].get_attribute('MSAName'),
        state_name[i].get_attribute('StateName'),
        county_name[i].get_attribute('CountyName')
                   ]
results_df = results_df.append({"Input": input_value, "MatchAddr": match_addr, "MSACode": msa_code, "StateCode": state_code, "CountyCode": county_code, "TractCode": tract_code, "MSAName": msa_name, "StateName": state_name, "CountyName": county_name}, ignore_index=True)
```

And these are the results I get:

```
"[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_17"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_18"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_19"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_20"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_21"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_22"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_23"")>]","[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session=""5212f4c1fa81af7c31eef9a087f42d52"", element=""A0D68D50DC114A180979E957959C017F_element_24"")>]",,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Instead of the actual table data that I get when running separately.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers. I'm not selecting the element anymore, but I'm still having an issue. Using this code:

```
for i in range(len(match_addr)):
    row = [
        match_addr[i].get_attribute('MatchAddr'),
        msa_code[i].get_attribute('MSACode'),
        state_code[i].get_attribute('StateCode'),
        county_code[i].get_attribute('CountyCode'),
        tract_code[i].get_attribute('TractCode'),
        msa_name[i].get_attribute('MSAName'),
        state_name[i].get_attribute('StateName'),
        county_name[i].get_attribute('CountyName')
    ]
    results_df = results_df.append({"Input": input_value, "MatchAddr": row[0], "MSACode": row[1], "StateCode": row[2], "CountyCode": row[3], "TractCode": row[4], "MSAName": row[5], "StateName": row[6], "CountyName": row[7]}, ignore_index=True)
```

gets these results:

```
  MatchAddr MSACode StateCode CountyCode TractCode MSAName StateName  \
0                                                                      

  CountyName tract_income_level underserved_distressed  \
0                           NaN                    NaN   

  MSA_estimated_median_income tract_estimated_median_income_2022  \
0                         NaN                                NaN   

  tract_median_income_2022 tract_median_income_pct tract_population  \
0                      NaN                     NaN              NaN   

  tract_minority_pct tract_minority_population owner_occupied_units  \
0                NaN                       NaN                  NaN   

  family_units_1_to_4                      Input  
0
```

Whereas when I run these separately in jupyter, I get the get the contents of the table:

```
# Find the table elements by IDs
match_addr = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'MatchAddr')
msa_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'MSACode')
state_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'StateCode')
county_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'CountyCode')
tract_code = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'TractCode')
msa_name = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'MSAName')
state_name = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'StateName')
county_name = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'CountyName')
```

```
# Create a list to store the scraped data
data = []
```

```
# Iterate over the elements and extract the text content
for i in range(len(match_addr)):
    row = [
        match_addr[i].text.strip(),
        msa_code[i].text.strip(),
        state_code[i].text.strip(),
        county_code[i].text.strip(),
        tract_code[i].text.strip(),
        msa_name[i].text.strip(),
        state_name[i].text.strip(),
        county_name[i].text.strip()
                   ]
    data.append(row)
```

I know I'm not putting this into a df on the separate queries, but other than that, I think these are pretty much the same. Any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks!

Comment: `for index, row in input_df.iterrows():` This loop at the top of the code is mostly useless -- it continually reassigns the `input_value` variable.  When the loop is over, `input_value` will contain only the street address of the last row in the dataframe.  Is this intentional?

Comment: No, that was unintentional.  Thanks for catching that! I've been trying to figure that part out as well. What should I do to address it?

Answer (score 0):

If the results you get are from the variable `results_df`, it is normal because you are not appending the attributes, but the web element objects. If you want to append the attribute you get from the elements, you should make this kind of adjustment to the code where you define `row`:

```
for i in range(len(match_addr)):
    row = [
        match_addr[i].get_attribute('MatchAddr'),
        msa_code[i].get_attribute('MSACode'),
        state_code[i].get_attribute('StateCode'),
        county_code[i].get_attribute('CountyCode'),
        tract_code[i].get_attribute('TractCode'),
        msa_name[i].get_attribute('MSAName'),
        state_name[i].get_attribute('StateName'),
        county_name[i].get_attribute('CountyName')
    ]
    results_df = results_df.append({"Input": input_value, "MatchAddr": row[0], "MSACode": row[1], "StateCode": row[2], "CountyCode": row[3], "TractCode": row[4], "MSAName": row[5], "StateName": row[6], "CountyName": row[7]}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That did stop the selection of the web element objects, but I'm still getting a null value saved to the dataframe. Could that be a problem of selecting the wrong row?

Comment: Which values are null? The dataframe entirely or the some values in the row? If the values in the row are null then the attributes you get are probably nonexistent

Comment: Added an update. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The values are null when in the dataframe, can you check if they are null when you fetch them? If the values return null just when you fetch them, that means the attribute does not return any value. Which causes them to be null in the dataframe too.